# Prove that the Euclidean Norm of any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same for any orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Consider the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $W$, and another basis $V = \{(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2)\}$ (written in coordinates of $W$). Show that the euclidean norm of any vector $(x,y)$ is the same for both bases.

So far, I have the following:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2.$ $\exists \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x = \alpha a_1 + \beta b_1, y = \alpha a_2 + \beta b_2.$ Then we can solve for $\alpha$ an $\beta$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
x &= \alpha a_1 + \beta b_1 \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{x - \beta b_1}{a_1} \\
y &= \alpha a_2 + \beta b_2 \Rightarrow  \alpha = \frac{y - \beta b_2}{a_2}  = \frac{x - \beta b_1}{a_1}\\
\Rightarrow \beta &= \frac{a_1y - a_2x }{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}, \alpha = \frac{b_2 x - b_1 y}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}.
\end{align*}

From here we plug into our euclidean norm:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2} &= \sqrt{\left(  \frac{b_2 x - b_1 y}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}\right)^{2} + \left( \frac{a_1y - a_2x }{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}  \right)^{2}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{b_{2}^{2} x^2 - 2 b_1 y b_2 x + b_{1}^{2} y^{2} + a_{1}^{2} y^2 -2 a_{2} x a_1 y + a_{2}^{2} x^2}{\left( a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1\right)^2}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(b_{2}^{2} + a_{2}^{2}) x^2 -2 (b_1b_2 + a_1a_2) xy + (b_{1}^{2} + a_{1}^{2}) y^2}{\left( a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1\right)^2}}
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, I am stuck here. I know that I am meant to somehow use the properties of orthonormality (i.e. $ a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2} = b_{1}^{2} + b_{2}^{2} = 1, a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = 0$), and I am supposed to show that the above expression is equal to $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, but I am not sure how to get to that point using the information I have.

Comment: This is not true. If $(a_1, a_2)= (3,4)$, then the Euclidian norm of $(a_1, a_2)$ in the standard basis is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$, but the coordinates of $(a_1, a_2)$ in any basis $\lbrace (a_1, a_2), (b_1, b_2) \rbrace$ are $(1,0)$, so its euclidian norm in such a basis is $1$.

Comment: That basis is not orthonormal. This is true only for orthonormal bases.

Comment: Of course, that's why I would advise you to add the precision in your question !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less computational strategy. $\lVert \:\cdot\:\rVert$ is independent of choice of basis if and only if $\lVert\:\cdot \:\rVert^2$ is, so we may as well use that. Now, if $(e_1,e_2)$ is one orthonormal basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $(f_1,f_2)$ is another, then the change of basis matrix $P$ is orthogonal so that $PP^T=I_2.$ If $f_1=ae_1+be_2$ and $f_2=ce_1+de_2$, and $v=m_1f_1+m_2f_2,$ then $Pv$ expresses $v$ in terms of $(e_1,e_2)$. So,
$$ \lVert v\rVert^2=\langle v,v\rangle=v^Tv=v^TP^TPv=\langle Pv,Pv\rangle=\lVert Pv\rVert^2.$$